# how to set UIView control fixed size ,Regardless iphone 3.5 the screen or iphone 4.0 screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a yellow `UIView`, I hope that its height is always maintained at 80 , but it will become a long screen of 4.0 , I want it to be fixed, so for that what should we do ?
Thank you!!

Why does not UIButton With the larger screen and larger it

Comment: set proper autoresizing masks in Xib.

Comment: But this need to cancel the automatic layout ? Another yellow UIView isroots UIView subviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An autosizing mask as shown (no resizing in the vertical or horizontal directions) will ensure that the UIView does not resize as the screen size changes.

[image: Autosizing Mask]

These settings can be found in the size inspector tab within utilities. You should see the autosizing options under the 'View' section.